# Does depressurising The Nest kill the eggs?

Tags: nemesis

If you use the Airlock Control room's room action to begin depressurisation in The Nest and the depressurisation completes successfully, do the eggs die or is The Nest destroyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You cannot target the Nest with the Airlock Control Room

(I don't have the rules on me so I can't give an exact reference, will add one shortly)

Depressuring with the Airlock Control can only target Yellow Rooms.
The Nest is not a yellow room (it doesn't have a color, as it can't be searched for any color of item)
Therefore, you cannot target the Nest with the Airlock Control Room

---

Edit:

Nemesis Rulebook, pg 25:

[image: From the rulebook]

Rules Text (Emphasis mine):

> Start Emergency Airlock procedure:
> Choose any 1 other **Yellow Room**. The Corridors connected to
> the Room you choose must not contain any Destroyed Doors 
> ...
>  **Yellow Room means a Room with a yellow background on the Action part**